# in linked list if i pass object data then searching code does not work

Tags: c#, search, linked-list

```
public bool Search (object x)
{
    Node current = head;
    while(current !=null)
    {
       if (current.data==x){              
           return true;                
       } current = current.next;  
    }      
    return false;
}
```

I have taken data as an object. It is not working in searching.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] to show how you are using this code?`

Comment: I tried out its working now ..as I am new to coding i got this problem and posted but later was able to  make it work ,,thanks